# Convert a Character Array to an Object Array in java? Is it possible?

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting, character

```
public static String doCensor(String toCensor)
{        
   Object[] aobj;
   int l = (aobj = toCensor.toCharArray()).length; //THIS LINE OF CODE IS THE PROBLEM
```

The reason I want to convert it to an object is so I can cast to either a specific character or string later. Is there any easier way to do this?

Casting examples:

```
char c = (char) aobj[j];
String word = (String) aobj[k];
```

Comment: It's possible, but it involves writing a loop.

Comment: any examples? I'm clueless lol

Comment: Why don't you just use a character array and use `Character.toString(char)` when you need a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is just to get the `char[]` from `toCharArray`, and then if you need a `String`, use `Character.toString(char)`.  You cannot cast a `char` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Object` representation of a `char` is a `Character`. You cannot cast a `Character` to a `String`. The easiest way to get a `String` from a `char` is to concat it with the empty `String`: `String s = ch + "";`. Or, since you are starting with a `String`, you could use [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to create a substring of 1 `char`.

Comment: That is neither the easiest nor the most efficient way to turn a character into a string.

Comment: @trutheality I was not talking about efficiency, I was talking about simplicity. That *is* the simplest way to get a `String` from a `char`. There are other ways to do it (`String#valueOf` and `Character#toString` being the first two that come to mind), but neither are as easy to understand for a beginner in Java, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe it is a matter of opinion, in my mind, adding non-numbers is much less intuitive than seeing "oh, this character is being converted *to* a *string*".

Answer (score 1):

You need not to convert String to array at all. You can extract characters from String directly:

```
char c=toCensor.charAt(j);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   String toCensor = "dog";
   char characters[] = new char[toCensor.length()];

   for(int i = 0; i < toCensor.length(); i++) {
                characters[i] = toCensor.charAt(i);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(characters[i] + " ");
   }
```

This breaks apart the String toCensor into characters and stores them into an array of characters. It then outputs `d o g`.
I'm not to sure what your asking but char is a primitive type and String is an Object. I'm almost posotive you can't cast char to object.

That is why the primitive type int can be an Integer but Integer cannot be an int, kind of like a square is a rectangle but a rectangle is not a square.
Also int does not have any methods but the Object type Integer does.
For example `Integer.toString(5)` or `String.format("")`

I hope this was helpful.